# SED find and replace not working as expected

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I can't seem to get my sed bash commands working correctly. What am I missing?

```
sudo sed -i '/^server-port=*/ c server-port=19132' /opt/bedrock_server/server.properties
sudo sed -i '/^server-portv6=*/ c server-portv6=19232' /opt/bedrock_server/server.properties
```

The first sed command replaces both lines in the server properties file. ie: server-port= and server-portv6=

How do I tweak this to only replace the intended line in the file.

Comment: Add a . in front of the * for zero or more of anything.  As is, it's zero or more equal signs.

Comment: ... imho it would be better to omit the `*` altogether in the context of the `c` command